# How to troubleshoot the snapshot command in Oracle NoSQL Database

Tags: oracle-nosql

The command “snapshot create” is showing the following message when something is not wrong. But there is not details about what was happened

```
kv -> snapshot create -name TEST
Create data snapshot succeeded but not on all components
Successfully backup configurations on sn1, sn2, sn3
```

Is there a way, to know the components failing ?
There is not a lot of information in the documentation about how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the flag -json. the JSON output shows more information and allow to see what exactly happened it

Here an example when everything is ok

```
snapshot create -name BACKUP -json 
{
 "operation" : "snapshot operation",
 "returnCode" : 5000,
 "description" : "Operation ends successfully",
 "returnValue" : {
   "snapshotName" : "210705-133631-BACKUP",
   "successSnapshots" : [ "admin1", "admin2", "rg1-rn1", "rg1-rn2", "rg1-rn3", "rg2-rn1", "rg2-rn2", "rg2-rn3", "rg3-rn1", "rg3-rn2", "rg3-rn3" ],
   "failureSnapshots" : [ ],
   "successSnapshotConfigs" : [ "sn1", "sn2", "sn3" ],
   "failureSnapshotConfigs" : [ ]
 }
}
```

Here an example when there is a failure

```
snapshot create -name BACKUP -json 
{
 "operation" : "snapshot operation",
 "returnCode" : 5500,
 "description" : "Operation ends successfully",
 "returnValue" : {
   "snapshotName" : "210705-133737-BACKUP",
   "successSnapshots" : [ "admin1", "admin2", "rg1-rn1", "rg1-rn2", "rg1-rn3", "rg2-rn1", "rg2-rn2", "rg2-rn3", "rg3-rn1", "rg3-rn2" ],
   "failureSnapshots" : [ "rg3-rn3" ],
   "successSnapshotConfigs" : [ "sn1", "sn2", "sn3" ],
   "failureSnapshotConfigs" : [ ]
 }
}
```

See the field returnCode.